# What will be the space requirements to upgrade to 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, 12.04

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to update it via Internet connection but I am not sure if my / partition has enough space.So what is the proper amount of free space required before upgrading to Ubuntu 12.04 from Ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: Have you resolved this question?

Answer (score 6):

The update should tell you how much space it will need before it goes ahead but an upgrade requires usually at least as much space as all the packages you have already installed take up.

This is because it needs to download all those packages before it can install them. That needs disk space.

If you're particularly worried, removing some of the bigger, non-essential applications that would be upgraded can help. You can reinstall them afterwards when the initial upgrade packages have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrade requires **2070M** for the 11.10 installation with the latest updates.

Answer (score -1):

You need at least a 4.4 GB space in your hard disk to install Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: yes to install, but if you upgrade you still have your 11.10 installation, you just replace and add some files.

Comment: @Alvar It does have to download a lot of new packages (`.deb` files) first, though, before anything old is removed or replaced.